# Intellisense doesn't work properly importing numpy (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Recently I noticed that when I import numpy as np, Intellisense doesn't suggest me things. For example, if I type "np.", nothing happens. Before it recommended me functions and so on.

I tried to write code on Spyder and everything works properly. I think it's a problem of Visual Studio Code.

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: It depends on the extension(s) you installed for VSCode

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure that you use the correct python interpreter which contains numpy pakcage.
2. Set `Pylance` as the Python Language Server. Add the following codes to your `settings.json`: `"python.languageServer": "Pylance"`,